# XDSoft DateTimePicker appending multiple divs to body

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using [XDSoft DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) within a modal.

1. When the modal opens I initialize the datetimepicker.
2. After initialization, I see a newly appended div at the bottom of the body. It's used to display the actual datetimepicker.
3. If I close the modal and then open it again, a second newly appended div appears at the bottom of the body.

If I use the destroy method should I expect these divs to be removed? Is there any way to clean them up?

```
$('#modal').html(html).foundation('reveal','open');

$('#date').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'m/d/Y'
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post the full code where you add the datetimepicker element?

Comment: The modal is called before where the html being passed in includes the date field. I then initialize the datetimepicker after the modal is opened.